# Function which applies a function passed as second parameter to each index of array pointed to by pointer s

Tags: c, function

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z627q.png)I have the following function:

```
void ft_striter(char *s, void (*f)(char *));
```

This function is meant to apply the function `f` to each index of the array pointed to by `s`.

I've seen the code to it but my problem is that I do not understand the function itself and how I would write a test for it. I would like to be able to understand it clearly and apply it. Can someone kindly break it down for me?

Please see the link to the function in question:

Comment: You have seen the code. We haven't. What kind of help or answer do you expect?

Comment: *"I've seen the code to it"* - then you're one up on us, because we haven't. We don't know how it works or what it does, so telling you how to test it would be folly. My pitiful slab of foggy glass excuse for a crystal ball says it does *something* for each sub-string in the string pointed to by `s`, in descending length as it moves up the sequence one char at a time. If [this is your function](https://github.com/illiatdesdindes/libft/blob/master/ft_striter.c), that's *exactly* what it does.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply. I'd like to apologise for not writing the function out - we are recoding the C library and these are part of the extra functions. We had to use the explanation I gave on what it does in order to code it, from this I made the assumption that you would understand what it does. Still getting used to this platform, I'll be better with my approach to asking next time - still have a lot of questions to clear.

Answer (score 1):

There is still something unclear in your question but I took the text literally:

`ft_striter()` iterates through string `s`. OP didn't define a termination condition. Hence, I used the usual – 0 terminator.

`do_something()` is another function to demonstrate how `f` is called. It is important that `do_something()` matches the signature required for parameter `f` in `ft_striter()`. Otherwise, in best case the compiler complains, in worst case – undefined behavior.

Sample code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void ft_striter(char *s, void (*f)(char*))
{
  for (; *s; ++s) f(s);
}

void do_something(char *s)
{
  printf("s: '%s'\n", s);
}

int main()
{
  char test[] = "Hello World.";
  ft_striter(test, &do_something);
  /* done */
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
s: 'Hello World.'
s: 'ello World.'
s: 'llo World.'
s: 'lo World.'
s: 'o World.'
s: ' World.'
s: 'World.'
s: 'orld.'
s: 'rld.'
s: 'ld.'
s: 'd.'
s: '.'
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo on wandbox**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/DorodTJgzvnXLGW8)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

considering you have a *null-terminated* `char*`

```
void ft_striter(char* str, void(*func)(char*)) {
    while (*str)
        func(str++);
}
```